# EnableComHosting with Self-Contained deployment

Tags: .net-core, .net-5

I have a WPF application and Ive created a COM wrapper to expose some internal functionality so we can talk to it from Excel VBA scripts.  This works very well until I try to install this.  When I publish for packaging with the installer I publish as self-contained so the user doesnt need to have the runtime installed.  If I do this, the comhost dll will not register.  I get 0x80008083 or 0x80008093 errors.

So, my choices I think are:

1. dont use self-contained (dont like this idea)
2. package the COM wrapper separately without self-contained and leave the main app self-contained. Not all users will use this wrapper but having to install the runtime is not great.
3. use another lang/framework for the wrapper?
4. maybe there is a way to register when it is self-contained?

Anyone got a suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an unsupported scenario. In [Exposing .NET Components to COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com#additional-notes) :

> Self-contained deployments of COM components are not supported. Only framework-dependent deployments of COM components are supported.

The reasons are explained in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/870):

> This is specifically blocked since success would be very hard to achieve unless there is only a single managed COM server in an application. The reason here is related to potentially having multiple CoreCLR instances in a single process.

Comment: @HansPassant oops, fixed

Comment: That is quite a short page, and yet, I still didn't scroll to the bottom and read the whole thing! :)  Looks like I'm going to have to use something other than .Net.  Thanks

Comment: @Jonesie I cheated. I started by googling the error numbers and found the Github issue which said this isn't supported. After that, I googled one of the phrases in the pull request to find the actual doc page, to check if anything changed since the issue was closed